# Wave packets as Fourier transforms

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, conventions, fourier-transform

I have recently been having a lot of trouble understanding wave packets. I get the point that adding multiple waves with various wave numbers introduces uncertainty in momentum which results in a localized position.

[image]

Now the integral sums over various wave numbers and introduces uncertainty in  momentum, but why do we have a 1/root 2pi infront of it. As far as I know since fourier transforms are easy to work with, we introduce it. It disapears or has no significance when the wave function is normalized. Is this right? And what determines the amount of uncertainty in momentum.

Comment: This is really a math question, The factor ensures symmetry between the FT and its inverse. You should have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem

Comment: So does the factor disappear when the wave function is normalized? and how do we introduce a fixed amount of uncertainty in momentum?

Comment: http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qmech/Quantum/node34.html  look or, better yet,  work your way down to equation 145. No offence intended , a bit of practice is the best way to remember .

Comment: We don't introduce Fourier transforms because they are *easy to work with*: they automatically emerge as they are the (most) general solutions to the Schrödinger equation, given boundary and domain conditions.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the specific domain and boundary conditions that makes fourier transforms a general solution rather than just the integration part?